# Bokeh cannot import name 'output_server'

Tags: pycharm, output, bokeh

I am trying to set up a server to run my bokeh code and output onto. Currently at the very beginner stage. When I run the below code, I face this error.

[image: Error]

````
output_server('line')

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

# add a line renderer
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2)

show(p)```
````

Comment: It has been removed: `#5989 Remove deprecated output_server`. There's a comment: "The `output_server` function is deprecated and will be removed in the near
future. Use `bokeh.client` functions such as `push_session` instead."

Comment: And it went away many years ago. Can you point to where you encountered anything that said to use `output_server`? Maybe we can edit or ask the author to remove.

Comment: I did not know that! Of course, I found it on here.  http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/server.html#creating-deployable-applications